# Azure forcing to create Standard LB while Basic LB is sufficient

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

I have referred to this link but that solution does not work.
[Basic Load Balancer with scale set "Virtual Machine Scale Set cannot use a basic SKU load balancer when singlePlacementGroup property is false (lar)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854281/basic-load-balancer-with-scale-set-virtual-machine-scale-set-cannot-use-a-basic)

Issue:
Azure forcing to create a Standard LB instead of Basic LB.
I created a VMSS with SinglePlacement Group = Enable
However while creating Basic Load Balancer, Azure does not allow me to add this VMSS to the backendpool and forces me to Create a STANDARD Load balancer and says “Single Placement Group is set to False” on the VMSS. While it is not true, see attached below screenshots.

Thanks
Venkat

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRSsF.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEV24.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV0sQ.jpg
```

Comment: Please edit your screenshot and Re-upload unable to view your attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I am getting the same error as below:

[image]

***To resolve this issue, try to recreate a virtual machine scale set in advance -> click fixed spreading and uncheck the Enable scaling beyond 100 instances***

[image]

And networking tab check whether you have provided correct virtual network from your resources as below. ***I have created load balancer -> vmss -> networking tab select load balancer created backend pool***

[image]

*Created virtual machine scale set:*

[image]

***After unchecking Enable scaling beyond 100 instances -> networking -> add load balancing -> use existing -> save***

[image]

My load balancing has been successfully added in virtual machine scale set in **Basic SKU**

[image]

---

***Additional details,*** I have created separate load balancer as basic and added to virtual machine scale set and check whether you have given correct ***frontend Ip as public, backend pool, health probes***

[image]

*Make sure to ***create load balancing rules*** as below:*

[image]

***Reference:*** [Virtual machine scale sets and placement groups - | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-placement-groups)

Comment: Hi Imran, You figured out a way. It is bit flaky though, you need to configure it in a certain way - first create Basic LB, then force it in VMSS (Networking). If I created VMSS first (not adding LB) and then created LB and added VMSS to bkpool, it doesn't (Either case, singlePlacementGroup was enabled). Maybe Azure team needs to be aware?? Your soln worked. Thanks!